# Source for quote about the cost of bread in the times before Moshiach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, money, messiah, bread, quotations

Does anyone know where it says that in the times before moshiach, it will cost a barrel of money to buy a loaf of bread? I remember hearing that, but can't find the source.

The reason I ask that is because I just read this quote from John Stossel, a libertarian journalist:

> John Stossel
>   The dollar has lost 96% of its value since #TheFed was created. By printing so much money, the Fed risks vicious inflation. So far, inflation has been mild, but when inflation increases, it happens quickly. I fear that soon, if we want to buy a loaf of bread, we’ll have to carry a wheelbarrow full of cash to the grocery store. STOSSEL tonight at 9PM on Fox Business.

Comment: By the way, Stossel was making a reference to the circumstances during a period of [hyperinflation in the Weimar Republic in 1923](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no such reference in Jewish sources.

But there is a source in Christian literature, in the New Testament.

*Revelation 6:6*

> And I heard a voice from among them say, "A loaf of wheat bread will cost a day's pay..."

The context of this quote is the Apocalypse (aka End of Days).

As mentioned by @Fred, this actually happened in Germany in the years leading to WW2.

[image: wheel barrow of money]

Comment: you make a barrel of money every day?

Comment: In pennies? Sure,

Comment: Also, the quote in the question says wheel barrow, not barrel.

Comment: On a Judaism Q&A site, shouldn't this answer be at most a comment (as one reference it brings is from Christian scripture, and the other from general history)?

Comment: @TamirEvan Edited per your comment

Answer (score 3):

The Gemara in Sotah (49b) says the price of wine will increase, but as far as I know it doesn't say the same about bread.

Comment: It's actually in the Mishna, Sotah 9:15.

Comment: @ShimonbM Not all editions of the Mishnah continue Sotah (ch. 9) after "משמת רבי בטלה ענווה ויראת חטא". That's why Rambam's and Bartenura's commentaries stop there. (See [Tosafot Yom Tov s.v. "רבי פנחס בן יאיר כו'"](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sotah.9.15?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Mishnah_Sotah.9.15.9&lang2=bi).)